# Какой  смысл использовать абстрактные классы? (PHP)

Tags: классы, php

Какой  смысл использовать абстрактные классы? (PHP)

Comment: troll detected ))

Comment: Какой смысл задавать вопрос без каких либо соображений по этому поводу?

------------------------------------

 - Отредактируйте вопрос
 - Напишите текст
 - Получите ответ

иначе просто заминусуют и испортят вам мнение о этом прекрасном сообществе :)

Comment: Изучайте шаблоны проектирования.

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы не совсем знаете ООП, тогда лучше почитайте про него. Без его знания лучше про абстрактные классы и не задумываться :)

А так, абстрактный класс предназначен для написание набросок приложения. То есть разработчик пишет программу, или некоторый функционал и если разработчик опытный, он для начала будет писать проектировку работы программы, а именно проектировку методов, который будет наследовать будущий класс. Абстрактный класс не несет в себе никакую функциональность, это только наброски. Особенно данные классы разрешают другим программистам разобраться в работе написанной программы.

Еще можно обратить внимание на интерфейсы, они по своей сути аналогичны абстрактным классам, но есть один нюанс: класс может наследовать только один абстрактный класс, а интерфейсов может наследовать несколько. 
С этого стоит правило, что абстрактный класс стоит писать если Вы хотите в уже рабочем классе полностью наследовать его, или же можно обойтись интерфейсами, которые будут зависит по частям.
Одни программисты пользуются в основном абстрактными классами, некоторые интерфейсами, но по настоящему опытные программисты уже на опыте знают где нужно прописать или интерфейс, или абстрактный класс.

Также, советую понять суть ООП, вот [статья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) на Вики

Answer (score 1):

Вот почитайте:

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.abstract.php

http://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/abstraktnyiy-klass-php.html